# OData Serialization and Deserialization

Tags: serialization, azure, servicestack, odata, azure-storage

I need to convert my custom class (c#) object into OData Json format and then convert it back to my object. Is there any library available to do this. I need something similar to the Newtonsoft.Json.

For example:

```
string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObject);
```

**Scenario (If you need to know):**

I am using Windows Azure Table Storage to save my objects. Client can save any kind of object (azure table storage limitations apply). Client will only connect to my service (ServiceStack) deployed as a web role on Windows Azure Cloud. This service will process the client request e.g. authenticate/authorize and then will connect to the table storage to save the object sent by client.

The main thing is my service (ServiceStack deployed as web role) doesn't know the class type of the object being sent by the client because client can create any new class and send its object for persistence. Windows Table Storage REST API supports OData. I am writing an SDK for client to send request to my service (web role). SDK will send the request after serializing the object into OData format so that my service can understand its schema as well.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is this because you are accessing an odata endpoint using httpclient?

Comment: No. I am not accessing an odata endpoint directly. My server side implementation (ServiceStack service) needs to understand the schema of the object serialized, process it and then send it to another server through odata endpoint.

Comment: Still trying to understand the exact issue. You have a service that calls another service. You need to process the services result and then send it back?

Comment: I have added the scenario on the bottom of the question. Hope that helps.

Comment: So you want a service to accept a string that has been serialized from a class that you have no knowledge of and then turn that into an EDM for the client to query later? Is this just on setup? By that I mean the client is just sending the serialized class the first time to describe the entity?

Comment: Client will always send the serialized odata string to the service. Is there any way i can serialize any C# POCO objects to OData format?

Comment: I guess I don't understand what you mean by "OData" format? You have either JSON or ATOM+XML.

Comment: Yes I meant JSON with metadata (property types).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, OData does NOT have serializer and deserializer independent of edm model. OData only serialize and deserialize objects when you have a model defining them, since you must convert the objects into values in OData format with the model.

Have you considered to use Azure Table SDK for .NET? AFAIK, Azure Table support self-defined types in the storage.

Plus, if you really need to do the serialization of your client objects, it seems you just need to serialize them on the client, then store the serialized strings in Azure Table. When you need to consume them, you can get the strings from Azure Table then deserialize them on your client.